# Regex to check for words before phrase

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will only return true if certain words don't show up before a phrase. For example, I want it to return True for this sentence "stop emailing me" and false for "Message me if you have that in stock. If not, stop emailing me".
This is as close as I could get and it doesn't work 
`^(?=(^(?:(?!(\bif\b)|(\or\b)).)\bstop emailing\b))`
Would also be great if I could keep it to looking just at words within 6 words or so.

Also, if possible I'd also like to check if a question was asked and if so then return false. I was trying to add something like `(?!\?)` and `(^(?:(?!(\. when\b)|(\. what\b)|(\. why\b)|(\. where\b)|(\. how\b)|(\. are\b)).)+$)` to the above but no success.

Thank you.

Comment: What about `"don't stop emailing me"`, or `"I will be angry if you don't stop emailing me"`

Comment: I don't think I'd see a lot of the first example and yea using just "if" would cause a problem with the second example, so I may just use "if not".

Comment: are you looking for 2 regexes, one for 'stop emailing me' and one for question asked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.match` along with conditional operator as mentioned below.

```
pattern = "stop\s+emailing\s+me"
result = True if re.match(pattern,content,re.M) else False
```

Another alternate solution is split the string as ,

```
string = "stop emailing me"
list = string.split()
True if list[0] = 'stop' and list[1] = 'emailing' and list[2] = 'me' else False
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately for this case I need all the conditions to be contained within the regular expression.